# Which Cypher query plan is faster?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here are two different queries, along with their plan.  The result of the query is exactly the same, but note that the query plan differs.

The key difference is between using `AllRelationships(identifier="r",...)` and `TraversalMatcher(trail="(n)-[r WHERE true AND true]->(m)", ...)`

Questions:

1. In general, which one is faster?   My guess would be that iterating through AllRelationships would be faster than running any traversal, but I don't know.
2. Would something like this be a target for optimization?  In this case, `return` doesn't include either `n` or `m` mentioned in the `MATCH` clause, this would suggest that the traversal isn't necessary.

Queries:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ profile start r=relationship(*) return count(r);
+----------+
| count(r) |
+----------+
| 100975   |
+----------+
1 row

ColumnFilter(symKeys=["  INTERNAL_AGGREGATEdd639fdf-1939-4b9c-ba36-213a0e79fff5"], returnItemNames=["count(r)"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
EagerAggregation(keys=[], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATEdd639fdf-1939-4b9c-ba36-213a0e79fff5,Count(r))"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
  AllRelationships(identifier="r", _rows=100975, _db_hits=100975)
neo4j-sh (?)$ profile match n-[r]->m return count(r);         
+----------+
| count(r) |
+----------+
| 100975   |
+----------+
1 row

ColumnFilter(symKeys=["  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE961900f2-76e0-40a0-bcab-5e8db2683859"], returnItemNames=["count(r)"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
EagerAggregation(keys=[], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE961900f2-76e0-40a0-bcab-5e8db2683859,Count(r))"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
  TraversalMatcher(trail="(n)-[r WHERE true AND true]->(m)", _rows=100975, _db_hits=301372)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the top query is faster because the listed number of db hits is smaller.  On the bottom query, I think it's iterating through all the nodes in the graph.  Try this, if you run:

```
start n=nodes(*) return count(n);
```

I bet you get: 301372